# How to remove all after space from string in angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular7, angular8

Tried to remove all after space and after underscore first letter should be caps from a string but not working.How do it in angular 8.If anyone know please help me to find a solution.

app.component.ts:

```
let content="power_managment 0vol";
alert(content.split( ).[0]);
// output should be like "powerManagment"
```

Comment: Is this the only case in which space is in between or space could be anywhere?

Comment: @Mridul: need to remove all after first space

Comment: Check if you want it like this to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```js
const capitalize = (s) => {
  if (typeof s !== 'string') return ''
  return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)
}

let content="power_managment 0vol 0vol 0vol 0vol0vol 0vol test 123vol";
let content2 = content.split(" ")[0].split("_");
console.log(content2[0] + "" + capitalize(content2[1]))
```

Comment: Can u check my question?

Comment: output should be like "powerManagment"

Comment: I updated my answer, but  this code will only be for cases with two words, do you have cases where  3 words are needed to be in the string?

Comment: content some time like this content="power_managment 0vol 0vol  0vol 0vol0vol 0vol 
 test  123vol";

Answer (score 1):

Try using `slice` and `indexOf` function

```
let content="power_managment 0vol";
content = content.slice(0, content.indexOf(' '));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let content="power_managment 0vol    ";
let trimmedContent = content.trim()
```